# informatica Datetime conversion to SQL server Timstamp

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, timestamp, type-conversion, informatica

I have a requirement where I have to load Informatica SESSSTARTTIME(datetime) to SQL server timestamp. When I am trying to connect datetime to timestamp I am getting error incompatible data type.

Any suggestions how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give more context, some code, what you expect and what happens, the error string you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in the past, where the date column was not getting loaded because of the difference in precision of date/time used by Informatica and SQL server. You can try this workaround: Change the data type in the target definition (not in SQL Server table, only in Informatica Target definition) to String, then Informatica will pass the date/time value in quotes when firing the insert query, which SQL server can convert to date/time automatically.

Answer (score 0):

in the mapping try to create output port in expression as sessionstarttime (which is a inbuilt variable) and pass it to target 
hope this will help to get desire output

in session there is config tab where you can change the format for date and time

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server **timestamp** datatype has nothing to do with time. It's an autogenerated number and you cannot load it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=SQL.90).aspx

quote:

"Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. timestamp is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime data type."